# Javascript "if" statement issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a function that is triggered when something on the check box field gets select. When an option is selected the script needs to go back, and see if a drop down field has a certain value. if that field has that certain value, then it needs to run the code that's inside the if statement. if not then it needs to skip that code and go to the next drop down.

The code is all working exactly how I need it to be from start to finish. The only problem is the if statements referencing the drop down don't work. no matter what value i select in the drop down field, the script runs.

So var carOp1-8 are the drop down fields. If the drop down field has selected "simplex" then I need the code inside it to run. Problem I am having is the code is running no matter what I select for the drop down field every time. is there something wrong with the sentex of the ' var carOp1... ' if statements?

I have also tried it with if (name == "this")

Here is the jsfiddle link so you can get an idea of what I am talking about.
 http://jsfiddle.net/upcQ8/ 
(on my form the page is automatically loaded when I hit the next button, I didn't know how to make that work on JSfiddle.

Here is the javascript I am using...

```
// Additional Options
$('input[name="item_meta[2002][]"]').change(function(){

var carOp1 = $("select[name='item_meta[2095]']").val();
var carOp2 = $("select[name='item_meta[399]']").val();
var carOp3 = $("select[name='item_meta[405]']").val();
var carOp4 = $("select[name='item_meta[402]']").val();
var carOp5 = $("select[name='item_meta[404]']").val();
var carOp6 = $("select[name='item_meta[403]']").val();
var carOp7 = $("select[name='item_meta[401]']").val();
var carOp8 = $("select[name='item_meta[400]']").val();

var simOpn1 = 0;

// Car 1 Simplex
if (carOp1 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open1").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open1").val();
}} 
// Car 2 Simplex
if (carOp2 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open2").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open2").val();
}} 
// Car 3 Simplex
if (carOp3 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open3").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open3").val();
}} 
// Car 4 Simplex
if (carOp4 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open4").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open4").val();
}} 
// Car 5 Simplex
if (carOp5 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open5").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open5").val();
}} 
// Car 6 Simplex
if (carOp6 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open6").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open6").val();
}} 
// Car 7 Simplex
if (carOp7 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open7").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open7").val();
}} 
// Car 8 Simplex
if (carOp8 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open8").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open8").val();
}} 

// Simplex 1 Car Call Security
if ($("input[name='item_meta[2002][]']:checked").val()=="Car Call Security"){   
    var carSec1 = simOpn1;

} else var carSec1 = 0;

    {$("#field_s1calc").val(carSec1).change();} 

});
```

Comment: You're using `=` in your ifs. It's `==`. A single `=` is an assignment. A `==` is the comparison.

Comment: Don't forget about case sensitivity also, `"simplex" !== "Simplex"`

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript you want to us '==' or '==='.  For strings it is best to use '===' when coding in javascript.

For example:

```
// Car 1 Simplex
if (carOp1 =="Simplex") {
var opn1 = $("#field_open1").val();
if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
    var simOpn1 = $("#field_open1").val();
}}
```

You have to remember that '=' is assigning a value to something. While '==' (and in javascript '===') is a comparison.

Edit: === also matches the type. So just use '=='.

Comment: === also matches the type. If you only use it when you know its strings, it's no better then ==

Comment: Additionally, you seem new to coding.  You can do the same thing in a for loop and basically remove all the repitions.  If you are coding and doing something over and over again you might not be doing it the best way. Now I'm not a jQuery or front-end guy so there is probably an even faster way.

Comment: @HugoDelsing I did say to use it for strings (its the only time I use it).  But i changed the code to only show ==.

Comment: @HugoDelsing I tried it the way you post it, but then nothing inside of if (carOp5 =="Simplex") {  } statement works what am I missing? If I do it this way if (carOp5 ="Simplex") {  } the comparison inside works but not the if statement. I am pretty new to this type of front end javascript coding so any kind of examples or explanations help. thanks again!

Comment: I ment that for @user2615862

Comment: Just to clear it up, the answer I get when I do it that way is always "0", but if I do it the "=" way then I get which ever number is largest, but if the number is not associated with "Simplex" it still gets chosen.

Comment: @user3638543 If nothing inside the if statement is happening when you do == that means it does not satisfy the comparison.  You do not want = as it assigns "Simplex" to the variable (and thats why everything inside it is ran, because its the next line of code).

if you are 100% sure that one of those does equal "Simplex" (not "simplex" or anything else) then try ===